# Have a function return JSX, then setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm new to React (and programming in general) and have come across an issue. I have created this component and using `react-copy-to-clipboard` package, `onCopy` I would like to copy a string, set `copied` to true and then after a couple of seconds set `copied` to false. When `copied` is true I want a div with some text to be displayed and when `copied` is set to false, I want it to disappear.

I have tried using `setTimeout` without success, as you can see in the code below and I suppose it's not working as I wish as the JSX doesn't re-render when the `copied` state is false again. I thought of using promises but couldn't figure out how to do that when I want to return JSX.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { CopyToClipboard } from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ClipBoard = () => {
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

  const onCopy = useCallback(() => {
    setTimeout(setCopied(false), 2000)
    setCopied(true);
    console.log(copied)
  }, [copied]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <section className="section">
        {copied ? <div><p>Copied</p></div> : null}
        <CopyToClipboard onCopy={onCopy} text="Text I want to copy">
          <button type="button">
            <span className="sr-only">
              E-mail
            </span>
            Text I want to copy
          </button>
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClipBoard;
```

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function - `setTimeout(() => setCopied(false), 2000)`, and move the `console.log()` out of the `onCopy` function to see the current balue of `copied`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The code is immediately invoking the state update to enqueue the `copied` state value to false.

```
setTimeout(
  setCopied(false), // <-- immediately called!
  2000
);
```

`setTimeout` expects a callback function that will be invoked when the timeout expires.

## Solution

Pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout` to be called when the timeout expires. Since React state updates are enqueued and asynchronously processed, the `console.log(copied)` will only log the unupdated `copied` state value closed over in callback scope from the current render cycle. If you want to log state values use the `useEffect` hook. Also, you should consider the edge case where the component unmounts prior to the timeout expiring and clear any running timers.

Full Example:

```
const ClipBoard = () => {
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);
  const timerRef = useRef(); // React ref for timer reference

  useEffect(() => {
    // Return cleanup function to clear timer when unmounting
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Effect to log any copied state updates
    console.log(copied);
  }, [copied]);

  const onCopy = useCallback(() => {
    timerRef.current = setTimeout( // save timer reference
      () => setCopied(false),      // function callback to update state
      2000,
    );
    setCopied(true);
  }, []); // empty dependency array

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <section className="section">
        {copied && <div><p>Copied</p></div>}
        <CopyToClipboard onCopy={onCopy} text="Text I want to copy">
          <button type="button">
            <span className="sr-only">
              E-mail
            </span>
            Text I want to copy
          </button>
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```